# Can we toggle off the score breakdown without refreshing page?

Tags: feature-request

After you gain 1,000 rep, you unlock the ability to see the breakdown of up votes vs. down votes.

Sometimes, I'm just curious to see the break down. I'll view it before reading an answer to see if it's controversial.

I find the display a little distracting, so I want to be able to toggle it again (by clicking the score again) to show the score normally. I know I can refresh the page, but it would disrupt my flow (and my Internet is sometimes slow).

I understand that the call to get the individual scores is costly, so the breakdown should be stored locally. This way, if someone just keeps clicking the score, toggling on and off, there's no need to query the database.

This is really a minor suggestion (just add 2 numbers with jQuery `:)` ), but I would REALLY appreciate having the functionality.

Comment: You could vote on the post and then retract it immediately. That should collapse to the combined vote count.

Comment: I endorse this sensible UI change.

Comment: I'm assuming the votes are done via an Ajax request via JQuery or similar.. if so it would be easy to reset the breakdown to 'normal' view.

Comment: The fact that this does not look like it will be fixed simply because Jeff (by my reading) does not seem to like the breakdown feature, and thus keeping it working in a non-intuitive manner, is my new pet SO peeve.

Comment: I endorse this UI change also and am curious if there is anything more that can be done to be proactive to make it happen. Two users have built solutions, there are currently 82 upvotes and only 3 downvotes on the question and a comment mentioning an endorsement has 22 upvotes. Is there anything more that can be done?

Answer (score 18):

**I totally agree** that Stack Overflow, well all the Stack Exchange sites **should have a feature to do this**. I find it very annoying, and it would take them only a few *minutes* to add.

I used to just vote up, then retract the vote (as **@SeinopSys** suggested in his answer).

However, seeing how highly voted this question is, I though I would write a script to share with the community:

[image: Demo]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Revert Vote Counts on Stack Exchange Websites
// @namespace   everywhere
// @include     *://*stackoverflow.com/*
// @include     *://*stackexchange.com/*
// @include     *://*askubuntu.com/*
// @include     *://*superuser.com/*
// @include     *://*serverfault.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

 // So you can tell the vote count section is clickable - OCD ;)
var style = $('<style>').text('.vote-count-post { cursor: pointer !important }')
$('head').append(style)

$('.vote-count-post').each(function() {
  $(this).attr('data-clicks', '0')                          // Set number of clicks to 0
})

$(document).on('click', '.vote-count-post', function() {
  clicks = parseInt($(this).attr('data-clicks'))            // Get number of clicks
  clicks++                                                  // Increase by 1
  $(this).attr('data-clicks', String(clicks))               // Write new number
  container = $(this)                                       // Stores the <span> so vote counts can be appended

  // If click is even (vote counts need to be hidden)
  if (clicks % 2 == 0) {
    title = $(this).attr('title')                           // In the format "XXX up / XXX down"

    upvotes = parseInt(title.match(/^\d+/)[0])              // Number of Upvotes
    downvotes = parseInt(title.match(/\d+(?= down$)/)[0])   // Number of Downvotes

    score = upvotes - downvotes                             // Score of post
    $(this).text(score)                                     // Replace the vote counts with the score
  }
  // If click is odd, and not 1 (vote counts need to be shownb)
  if ((clicks % 2 != 0) && (clicks != 1)) {
    postID = $(this).siblings('input').val()                // This input stores the ID of the Post (part of SE HTML)
    $.ajax({                                                // AJAX to URL *.stackoverflow.com/posts/#postID#/vote-counts
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/posts/' + postID + '/vote-counts',
      dataType: "json",                                     // Data is stored as a JSON
      success: function(json) {
        var html =                                          // Creating the HTML for the Vote Counts
          '<div class="vote-count" style="color:green">' + json['up'] + '</div>' +
          '<div class="vote-count-separator"></div>' +
          '<div class="vote-count" style="color:maroon">' + json['down'] + '</div>';
        $(container).html(html)                             // Append the HTML
      }
    })
   }
})
```

The Stack Exchange script gets the data for the vote counts from a page, `http://stackoverflow.com/posts/#postID#/vote-counts`, so this script uses an [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request to get that page.

The data is stored in a JSON array, with the upvotes and downvotes being accessed via `json['up']` and `json['down']` respectively. It then creates the HTML, and adds it to the page.

I created a [**Gist**](https://gist.github.com/Druzion/dcdbc62bd2387ced3395072f54303bf9/raw/547c7c6657e7027fd36dac7cb832932e749d611e/RevertVoteCounts.user.js) to install the script

Comment: Maybe you can add it so the cursor becomes a hand when hovering over the expanded votes?

Comment: @RAnders00 No Problem! Done! It seems that when you see the Vote Counts, the `.css()` that was added was overwritten. I guess I could add a stylesheet though instead of listening for `hover`...

Comment: @RAnders00 I just changed it to use a stylesheet instead of using `.css()` and the `hover` event, it is much more efficient!

Comment: @RAnders00 Nice, thanks!

Comment: You can adjust your match rules to `*://*.stackoverflow.com/*` and it'll catch both `http` and `https` protocols and will catch meta sites as well.  That would reduce your match rules from 4 to 1. I would also suggest adding the questions portion of the path as well so you're not needlessly running your script on pages that don't need it. :)

Comment: @ᴉʞuǝ I thought so, thank for clarifying that!

Comment: @RAnders00 Do not worry about updating the link, I created a [**Gist**](https://gist.github.com/Druzion/dcdbc62bd2387ced3395072f54303bf9/raw/1ce0e5a2665a46eea9453f66809f21e03a4247d3/RevertVoteCounts.user.js) for it

Comment: First, you need to rename the script to something that ends with `.user.js` (you can use my PR for that) and the you can use [this link](https://cdn.rawgit.com/Druzion/StackExchange-RevertVoteCounts/master/RevertVotes.user.js) (you get this link on [rawgit.com](https://rawgit.com/))

Comment: @RAnders00 Yup, I just found out! I spend the last 20 minutes figuring it out..., thanks! (By the way, I'll remove the repository, and just keep the Gist)

Answer (score 10):

As others have stated, I too agree with this feature-request. I don't really see any harm in allowing this.

I did a little digging and found the code that handles fetching the vote counts, the following is a portion of that code.

```
$score
    .html(html)
    .unbind('click')
    .data('bound', false)
    .css('cursor', 'default')
    .attr('title', (function(n) {
        return n.upCount == 1 && n.downCount == 1 ? n.upCount + " up / " + n.downCount + " down" : n.upCount == 1 ? n.upCount + " up / " + n.downCount + " down" : (n.downCount == 1, n.upCount + " up / " + n.downCount + " down")
    })({
        upCount: Math.abs(+json.up),
        downCount: Math.abs(+json.down)
    }));
```

As you can see the click event is unbound to prevent further action.

Overall, I think this would be pretty simple to fix..

- Remove to call to unbind the click event
- Wire up a click event on the vote scores that replaces the counts with the score

I took the liberty of writing up a fix for it up real quick.

```
var fetchVoteCounts = function($score) {
    if (loadingVotes) return;

    loadingVotes = true;

    var postId = fetchVoteCountsPostId($score);
    $score.addSpinner();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/posts/{postId}/vote-counts'.formatUnicorn({
            postId: postId
        }),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(json) {
            StackExchange.helpers.removeMessages();

            var html =
                '<div class="vote-count" style="color:green">' + json.up + '</div>' +
                '<div class="vote-count-separator"></div>' +
                '<div class="vote-count" style="color:maroon">' + json.down + '</div>';

            $score
                .html(html)
                .data('bound', false)
                .css('cursor', 'default')
                .attr('title', (function(n) {
                    return n.upCount == 1 && n.downCount == 1 ? n.upCount + " up / " + n.downCount + " down" : n.upCount == 1 ? n.upCount + " up / " + n.downCount + " down" : (n.downCount == 1, n.upCount + " up / " + n.downCount + " down")
                })({
                    upCount: Math.abs(+json.up),
                    downCount: Math.abs(+json.down)
                }));

            $score.find('.vote-count').on('click', function() {
                $score
                    .empty()
                    .text(Math.abs(+json.up) - Math.abs(+json.down))
                    .attr('title', 'View upvote and downvote totals');
            });
        },
        error: function(res, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $score.removeSpinner().parent().showErrorMessage((res.responseText && res.responseText.length < 100 ? res.responseText : "An error occurred during vote count fetch"), {
                transient: res.status == 409
            }); // fade away throttle errors
        },
        complete: function() {
            loadingVotes = false;
        }
    });
};
```

If adding this feature-request is out of the question, [here is a UserScript](https://gist.github.com/enki-code/31a63a90a1d0fe8b3db57e866e2f3ae3/raw/71647b6d1ce6c5da9b161b7e065da3d46d9581f8/toggle-votes.user.js) that toggles that vote counts and rebinds the click events.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Toggle Vote Count
// @version      1.0
// @author       ᴉʞuǝ
// @namespace    https://github.com/enki-code
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/questions/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';
(function($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings) {
        if(settings.url.indexOf('vote-counts') > -1){
            $('.vote-count-post div').one('click', function(){
                var $vote = $(this).parent(),
                    upvotes = +$vote.find('div:first-child').text(),
                    downvotes = +$vote.find('div:nth-child(3)').text(),
                    score = Math.abs(upvotes) - Math.abs(downvotes);

                var $score = $('<span/>', {
                    text: score,
                    class: 'vote-count-post',
                    title: 'View upvote and downvote totals',
                    style: 'cursor: pointer;',
                    itemprop: 'upvoteCount'
                });

                $vote.replaceWith($score);
                StackExchange.vote.bindFetchVoteCounts();
            });
        }
    });
}(jQuery));
```

End result:

[image: vote count toggle]

Comment: I am new to using Git. I created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/Druzion/dcdbc62bd2387ced3395072f54303bf9) for mine, but cannot work out how you link in such a way, Greasemonkey detects it as a script and installs it (like your one). Can you tell me how you did this?

Comment: @Druzion if you link to the 'raw' version of the Gist, then greasemonkey/tampermonkey detects it :) (for your Gist, that would be https://gist.github.com/Druzion/dcdbc62bd2387ced3395072f54303bf9/raw/ee428859a885f1f729195c70d1f95d29fde50cd8/RevertVoteCounts.js)

Answer (score 7):

You can upvote, then immediately undo it, and the counter will be reset. This works on your own posts, too.

> [image: Demo]

Comment: Seems like a pretty hacky workaround to me. I think it would be better if you could toggle it back by just clicking on one of the broken down scores like the OP requested.

Comment: @RobH Knowing the SO Dev Team's affinity towards adding minor things like this, I highly doubt that's happening any time soon. (Unless someone writes a userscript for it)

Comment: How did you get the animated vote buttons ?

Comment: @SeinopSys But I suggested they use jquery. How can they resist?

Comment: @JonasCz https://github.com/soscripted/sox

Comment: I don't like this approach at all. It's very frustrating to see an answer of yours be upvoted only for the vote to disappear a moment later. Also it just feels very wrong to vote on a post (even temporarily) just to affect a UI change.

Comment: And what happens if you've already voted on the question and your vote is locked?

Comment: @SeinopSys Just look at [this bug report I made](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253332/238826) which still makes my eyes bleed every time I upvote a comment

Comment: @NicolBolas then it will show message and reset counter. no need of retract.

Comment: I find it amusing that doing this vote-and-unvote thing will not only reset the score to the single number for oneself, but for *everyone else* currently looking at the same page too, since dynamic updates of the vote score have that effect on the score breakdown.

Comment: @ApproachingDarknessFish Ok, then it would be better to downvote and retract the vote. That way you'll be happy to see the vote go away.

Comment: @user3386109 That feels even worse for some reason.

Comment: What if you want to vote but keep the current score breakdown? Voting and the score breakdown should be two separate things - not linked.

Comment: @Druzion ShareX